# Last four digits

Tags: number-theory

Find the last four digits of $$n=2^{2026}-2^{2020}-2^{2019}$$. I have no idea about that. Also 5th grade problem. Thx.

Comment: Well, you could take $2^{2019}$ as a common factor, to start ...

Comment: Found them. You are welcome!

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 3):

We can rewrite the number as follows:

$$2^{2026} - 2^{2020} - 2^{2019} = 2^{2019} (2^7 - 2^1 - 2^0) = 2^{2016} \cdot 2^3 \cdot (128 - 2 - 1) = 16^{504} \cdot 1000$$

The last four digits thus equal $6000$.